# MATLAB giving me NAN values, can't figure out why

Tags: matlab, mean

I'm sure whatever the problem here is pretty simple, but I cannot figure it out at all.

I have a very simple data file. It is a .csv file with a column of labels, and a column of values associated with each label. I am trying to do some simple operations involving the vector, but MATLAB keeps giving me NaN values.

Even if I just do `mean(vector)` I get an NaN!

I can't figure out why. There are NO NaN values in the vector. It is all numeric. I typed the command `isnumeric(vector)` and got a value of 1. I used a for loop to cycle through every value in the vector, and all of them are numeric.

I have copied all of the data into a new csv file and tried that. Still just gives me NaN.

I cannot at all figure out what is going on here. I have no problems doing the same with other vectors. The problem is MATLAB won't tell me WHERE or WHAT the problem is, it only gives me NaN.

Any theories on what is going on, here? Or any idea of some way to check the vector to see what MATLAB is having trouble reading?

I am using Matlab R2008a, on a Mac.

Comment: Without seeing the vector we can do nothing. But we don't need to. What you need to do is slowly whittle down your input data to isolate the values that are causing your problem. Do a binary search.

Comment: I realize that, but given there are 8000 values, I was hoping people would have a suggestion for HOW to isolate the problem values. Thus the last question in my post. What is the best way to figure this out?

Comment: Cut your CSV in half. Try both halves. Repeat with the broken half. That's a binary search. If *both* halves are messed up, then perhaps all of your data is bogus - in which case you can post three lines of it here.

Comment: You could also try find(isnan(data)) on the data you have read into matlab to find which values are turning into NaNs.

Comment: isnumeric counts NaN and Inf as numbers.

Comment: If once you find out which elements are returning `NaN` and they appear normal in the file, you can try reading in the file using another function such as `importdata` or `dlmread` to see if those work better than `csvread`.

Answer (score 3):

This will return the indices of your data that are supposedly `NaN`:

```
find(isnan(vector))
```

You can also use the [`nanmean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html) function in the Statistics Toolbox, which ignores `NaN` values in the data. There are actually nan- versions of many of the other common stats functions as `NaN` is often used to denote an empty or "missing" value in datasets.

Another way you could possibly get `NaN` from `mean(vector)` without having any such values in your data is if both `Inf` and `-Inf` appear there. I.e., `mean([-Inf 1 2 3 Inf])` returns `NaN`. To check for this, you can do the following:

```
any(vector==Inf) && any(vector==-Inf)
```

Then you can do

```
find(isinf(vector))
```

to find the indices. Lastly, `find(~isfinite(vector))` would find both `NaN` and infinite values.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that `isnumeric` returns true for both NaNs and Infs. as well as actual numbers. It's meant to distinguish between numeric-like values and other things (e.g., function handles or cell arrays). Use `isnan` (to detect NaNs), or `isfinite` (to detect Infs and NaNs).

That should at least let you find the NaNs, but next you need to figure out where they're coming from. `cvsread` is not particularly smart (it's just a glorified call to `textscan` in recent versions) and wants all-numeric data.

Could you have a header row with text labels in it, stray spaces, weirdly formatted negatives (e.g., accounting-style parenthised negatives (34)), or even hex/octal numbers (e.g., 0x42)? Note that the entire file must be numeric *EVEN* if you specify a range, which is weird and annoying.